# what is Logo in search engine?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-search

does any one have idea about Logo in search engine , https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/logo

and what is the use of this ? and where to place this script ?

```
   <script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "NewsArticle",
  "mainEntityOfPage": {
    "@type": "WebPage",
    "@id": "https://google.com/article"
  },
  "headline": "Article headline",
  "image": [
    "https://example.com/photos/1x1/photo.jpg",
    "https://example.com/photos/4x3/photo.jpg",
    "https://example.com/photos/16x9/photo.jpg"
   ],
  "datePublished": "2015-02-05T08:00:00+08:00",
  "dateModified": "2015-02-05T09:20:00+08:00",
  "author": {
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "John Doe"
  },
   "publisher": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "Google",
    "logo": {
      "@type": "ImageObject",
      "url": "https://google.com/logo.jpg"
    }
  },
  "description": "A most wonderful article"
}
</script>
```

Comment: The logo property is a sub-property of the image property.

Comment: hi @AravindS i was asking how and where to use this ?

Comment: You can use it like `<script type="application/ld+json">
      {
      "@context": "http://schema.org/",
      "@type": "Organization",
      "url": "http://www.yourcompany.com/",
      "logo": "http://www.yourcompany.com/logo.png"
      }
    </script>`

Comment: hi @AravindS , i think you are not understanding my question , where to paste this script and how do i debug this , and what is the purpose for this ?

Comment: Oops! i am debugging by JSON code out here https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool , if its not helped, ignore

Comment: _“and what is the purpose for this ?”_ - that is explained on the very page you yourself linked to - so what exactly are you having trouble understanding? _“where to paste this script and how do i debug this”_ - all that info can be found if you just follow the links in the sub-navigation on that page. Under “Introduction to structured data” you find where to put this, and “Build, Test, and Release Your Structured Data” explains how to debug it. If you are trying to “get into new stuff”, then please at least make the effort to have a proper look around in the documentation.